# What's the measure of the segment $PD$ in the rhombus below?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference : Let $M$ and $N$ be the midpoints of the sides $AB$ and $AD$ of a rhombus $ABCD$.
Calculate $PD$, if $MP= 6, (P = MD \cap CN$)

My progress:
[image]

G is centroide

$\triangle ABD\\
GM = \frac{2M}{3}\\
GM = 2DG = 2(GP+DP)\\
MD = 3DG\\
GM = 6 -GP\\
\therefore 6 - GP = 2GP+2DP \implies \\
2DP = 6 - 3GP$

There is one more relationship to finish...
$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say $CN$ intersects $BD$ at $R$.

$BH$ and $CM$ are medians of $\triangle ABC$.

Therefore $Q$ is the centroid of $\triangle ABC$. So $BQ:QH=2:1$. From there we can see $BQ=QR=RD$.

Also from midpoint theorem to $\triangle ABD$ we found $MN=\dfrac12BD$.

Hence $MN=\dfrac32RD$.

Now, $\triangle MNP\sim\triangle DRP\implies\dfrac{MN}{RD}=\dfrac{MP}{PD}=\dfrac32\implies PD=4.$

Comment: Nice answer but you should simplify your work. There is no reason for angle bisector etc. As $H$ and $M$ are midpoints of sides $AC$ and $AB$ respectively, $Q$ is center of $\triangle ABC$. Similarly $R$ is center of $\triangle ADC$. Then on it's all good.

Comment: @petaarantes once ACB makes the changes, this is a more straightforward solution and I think you should accept this one.

Comment: ok...solution accepted

Comment: @MathLover I've already realized that, and I came to change it : )

Answer (score 2):

As $\triangle NGM \sim \triangle BGD$, $DG = 2 GM$ as you mentioned. Also, $GH = \dfrac{AH}{3}$.

In $\triangle AGD$, traversal $NC$ intersects $AD$ and $GD$ internally and $AG$ externally. Applying Menelaus's theorem,

$ \displaystyle \frac{AC}{CG} \cdot \frac{GP}{PD} \cdot \frac{DN}{NA} = 1$

$ \displaystyle \frac{2 AH}{4AH/3} \cdot \frac{GP}{PD} = 1 \implies PD = \frac{3}{2} GP$

and we obtain $ ~ 5 GP = 4GM$

As $MP = 6, GP = \dfrac{8}{3} \implies PD = 4$

Answer (score 1):

One can use a simple approach using equations of lines. Let $H$ be the origin, $C$ be at $(2\alpha,0)$ and $B$ at $(0,2\beta)$. Then $M=(-\alpha,\beta)$, $N=(-\alpha,-\beta)$, and $D=(0,-2\beta)$. Then we write the equation for $MD$:
$$\frac{x-x_M}{x_D-x_M}=\frac{y-y_M}{y_D-y_M}\\\frac{x+\alpha}{\alpha}=\frac{y-\beta}{-2\beta-\beta}\\y=-\frac{3\beta}\alpha x-2\beta$$
Similarly, for $NC$:
$$\frac{x-x_N}{x_c-x_N}=\frac{y-y_N}{y_C-y_N}\\\frac{x+\alpha}{3\alpha}=\frac{y+\beta}{\beta}\\y=\frac{\beta}{3\alpha} x-\frac23\beta$$

When we write the intersection (point $P$), we get:
$$-\frac{3\beta}\alpha x_P-2\beta=\frac{\beta}{3\alpha} x_P-\frac23\beta\\
x_P=-\frac{4}{10}\alpha$$
Now draw perpendiculars from $P$ and $M$ to $BD$. You get similar triangles. You can then write $$\frac{MD}{PD}=\frac{6+PD}{PD}=\frac{\alpha}{\frac4{10}\alpha}=\frac{10}4$$
This yields $PD=4$

Comment: You are welcome. I don't always remember some of the theorems.